# 0xc0000005 When starting .Net process

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit

We have a .Net application for a long time now. All the .exe set to be x86 (both realease and debug configurations)

We just released a new version and suddenly, our executable will not start on specific Windows 7 64 bit machines.

The event viewer reports: 0xc0000005 (Access violation)

After stripping down our application to the minimum (One reference to one of our assembly, one line in Main() : Console.ReadKey(), app.config file empty) the problem still occurs.

The only way to make it work is to set the platform target to AnyCPU, which is not suitable because we use 3rdParty components.

Any idea why I have this issue? Any possible solution?

Comment: What does "specific" mean?  What's special about them?  Start killing processes one-by-one to find the troublemaker.  Start with the anti-malware.

Comment: Specific means that we have many clients running W7 64 and only one of our customer reported the problem. I'll try to remove the anti-malware / anti-virus. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

.Net and 0xc0000005 are a known issue that Karel Zikmund at Microsoft has explained in good detail over the years. Below are his MSDN posts from his earlier to more resent so you can see the whole thread and how others have been impacted and how in many cases they worked through it.  How one of these threads can help you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/25ce2de0-1556-4f1f-979d-420bdd212abf

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/2b89ca3a-6a93-4d21-a5eb-d5b5d44c6dce

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/clr/thread/dd3be208-c46c-4a5d-94ce-f93766c9d122